# Accessing Nested For Loop Indexes

Tags: java

Does the for loop below in java visit all indexes of adjacencyMatrix or does it only do

```
adjacencyMatrix[1][1]; 
adjacencyMatrix[2][2]; 
adjacencyMatrix[3][3]; 
adjacencyMatrix[4][4];
```

etc.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_nodes; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_nodes; j++)
            adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = adjacency_matrix[i][j];
```

Thanks

Comment: In Java, arrays are indexed starting at 0.

Comment: Step through in a debugger or output the value of i & j at each (nested) loop iteration. That will give you your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will *not* visit all indexes of the array because array indexes begin at 0, not 1. In other words, the first element of the 2D array would be *adjacencyMatrix[0][0]* so you should start both of your iterations from 0.

If the array has a length of 5, the largest index would therefore be four so be careful how far you iterate.

**For example, if you did:**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_nodes; i++)
    for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_nodes; j++)
        adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = adjacency_matrix[i][j];
```

*Then* it would visit:

```
adjacencyMatrix[1][1]; 
adjacencyMatrix[1][2]; 
adjacencyMatrix[2][1]; 
adjacencyMatrix[2][2]; 

etc...
```

**If you did:**

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_nodes; i++)
        adjacencyMatrix[i][i] = adjacency_matrix[i][i];
```

*Then* it would visit:

```
adjacencyMatrix[1][1]; 
adjacencyMatrix[2][2]; 
adjacencyMatrix[3][3]; 
adjacencyMatrix[4][4];
```

Comment: Please do not support people that show no effort at all to solve their "problem"

Answer (score -2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_nodes; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < number_of_nodes; j++)
        adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = adjacency_matrix[i][j];
```

Comment: Please do not support people that show no effort at all to solve their "problem".

Comment: I just want to help him.